# How to access Entity Framework foreign key object

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, razor

I am creating an ASP.NET project with Entity Framework and having a hard time understanding how to access a foreign key object in Entity Framework.

I have a model set up something like this:

```
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Setup ID")]
    public int SetupId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SetupDetails")]
    [Display(Name = "Setup Details")]
    public int SetupDetailsId { get; set; }
```

It is worth noting `SetupDetails` is in its own table, and we are in a table called `Setup`. So when I create an object, I want to be able to access something like this:

```
setup.setupdetails.Name
```

So from my understanding I need to create and object inside of the object "Setups" like so:

```
    public SetupDetails SetupDetails { get; set; }
```

However when I do this this we are getting a null pointer exception which obviously we know it exists if it is a foreign key.

Do I just need to convert the int to the `SetupDetails` class? If I change this datatype I get an error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Setup.SetupDetailsId' of type 'SetupDetails'.

Comment: Create virtual type in Setups model, `public Virtual SetupDetails SetupDetails { get; set; }` And also while accessing setupdetails, `setup.setupdetails?.Name` use like this

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achive in here needs what we called a "navigation property".

```
[Display(Name = "Setup Details")]
public int? SetupDetailsId { get; set; }
public SetupDetails SetupDetails { get; set; }
```

And when you try to get this data, for example:

```
public void SomeMethod(int setupId)
{
    //_context is your DbContext.
    var setup = _context.Setup.Where(i => i.SetupId == setupId)
                              .Include(i=>i.SetupDetails)
                              .FirstOrDefault();

   //Now you can reach the "SetupDetails" value with => setup.SetupDetails.Name
   var setupDetailsName = setup.SetupDetails.Name;
}
```

Comment: If SetupDetails data is null for that setupId, it throws exception.